# enzyme coverage report showing inbuild function as uncover function in coverage report

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, typescript2.0

in React i am using jest and enzyme library for testing i am pretty new to it. in Istanbul coverage report when i am testing i can see following statement mark as uncovered branches and uncovered function can you guys give me some ideas how can i move forward with it because it's showing default methods like find, map in uncover part and also how can i avoid those branches any help appreciate.

[image]

[image]

[image]